Countable Dense Unions of Non-singleton Closed Intervals?
Is there a characterization for dense subsets $D\subseteq [0,1]$ that can be written as a countable union of non-singleton closed intervals (that is, closed intervals with nonempty interior)? I know that a necessary condition is that
$$(\star)\ \forall U\subseteq [0,1] \text{ open}:\text{Int}(U\cap D)\neq\emptyset$$
and also being $F_\sigma$. However, I don’t really know if both of these conditions suffice although I do believe so. Also, does the condition $(\star)$ correspond to some known condition in the literature. It seems to be somewhat stronger than being dense.

Of course you mean $\forall U \subseteq [0,1]$ open and nonempty.

Condition (*) and being $F_\sigma$ is not sufficient.  For a counterexample,
take the union of a Cantor set $S$ (or any closed, nonempty and nowhere dense set)
and a sequence of non-singleton closed intervals $J_i$, chosen recursively, such that $S$ and the $J_i$ are pairwise disjoint and their union contains every rational in $[0,1]$.
